# How to simulate incoming call?

Tags: android, automated-tests, adb, telnet

I found that it's possible to make it on emulator device:

```
# connects to device
telnet localhost 5554
# set the power level
power status full
power status charging
# make a call to the device
gsm call 012041293123
# send a sms to the device
sms send 12345 Will be home soon
# set the geo location
geo fix 48 51
```

From [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCommandLine/article.html#telnet-to-your-android-device),
but when I insert :

```
telnet localhost 5554
```

I get following:

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Probably it is not helping me because i need to fake cal for real device conncted to computer. i need some adb shell command.

Comment: Which OS are you running?

Comment: I'am using ubuntu 16.10

Comment: I found that i can call from real device:                                                       
 adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL tel:1112223333, but i would prefer not using real device and just fake incoming call from command line

Answer (score 1):

You can do it directly from the emulator settings gui, clicking on the three dots, then 'phone':

[image]

Comment: I'am testing  real devices , and as far as I know i can't call real device from avd .

Comment: @mordi True. I don't think there's any possibility to simulate a call on a real device. The approach with telneting into localhost also only works for emulators.